# Excel vlookup map to network drive (not mapped to H,N so on)

Tags: microsoft-excel, network-drive, vlookup

I'm trying to use use vlookup to access another excelsheet on a network drive.

Currently I have a vlookup that works fine

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;'H:\CVO\[test.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$C$4;2;)
```

However I cannot seem exhange the `H:\` with the server address `//pcpfile10/Corporate/`.

I need to link to the network address, since other users do not necessary have H-drive mapped to the same server as I do.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Don't you need to use backslashes instead if it is local?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it should be back or forward, but it didn't fix the error - but I accidently found the error while testing it so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was excel autocorrect when pressing ENTER, which "fixed" the link to include a letter link.

If I added the correct network link (using backslashs), and simply clicked away from the field, then excel didn't try to fix it with an error.